# Managing multiple remote user accounts and pubkeys with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to work out a way to manage a single user's pubkey across multiple sites, as well as dropping that key into multiple *$HOME* directories. Reason being; our devs login as themselves to check on things, run `sudo` etc, however they deploy code as a *passenger* user over SSH so their pubkey needs to be in *~/home/passenger/.ssh/authorized_keys* as well.

I'm not sure if changing `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` would make this less crazy but since I'm almost there with my current playbook, I thought I'd post the question as-is and see what comes of it. Perhaps this would indeed be better solved another way.

In my `homedirs.yml` file, I create user's home directories (they exist in LDAP) and then move their pubkey into place. This works fine for their own home directory, but the `passenger` user needs this key as well. Since I may use this playbook for other users and hosts,  I have defined a `to_user:` list which defines which home directories the pubkey should be setup for.

How do I loop over the `{{ item.to_user }}` list in the `authorized_key:` play where `{{ item.name }}` is currently referenced?

playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - ../group_vars/homedirs.yml
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set up home directory
      when: inventory_hostname in item.allowed_hosts
      file:
        path: "/home/{{ item.name }}"
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ item.name }}"
        group: "{{ item.group }}"
        mode : 0750
      with_items: "{{ homedirs }}"


    - name: setup ssh pub key
      when: inventory_hostname in item.allowed_hosts
      authorized_key:
        user: '{{ item.name }}'
        state: present
        key: '{{ item.pubkey }}'
      with_items: "{{ homedirs }}"
```

**homedirs.yml**

```
# homedirs.yml
homedirs:
  - name   : usr123
    group  : developers
    pubkey :  "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/user123@somehost.pub') }}"
    to_user:
      - user123
      - passenger
    allowed_hosts  :
      - web1.my.com
      - web1.test.my.com

  - name   : usr555
    group  : admin
    pubkey :  "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/user555@somehost.pub') }}"
    to_user:
      - user555
      - sysadmin
    allowed_hosts  :
      - blah.blah.host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic requirement for a [`with_subelements` loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) in Ansible:

```
- name: Set up home directory
  when: inventory_hostname in item.0.allowed_hosts
  file:
    path: "/home/{{ item.1 }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ item.1 }}"
    group: "{{ item.0.group }}"
    mode : 0750
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ homedirs }}"
    - to_user
```